# Android VideoView stop streaming after specific time

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, android-videoview

I am playing live stream from [this URL](http://ns3622101.ip-149-202-201.eu:8000/live/fr443500/75019pa/286.ts) in android

So far, I have managed to play the video in videoView,  the problem was the video stopped exactly after 23 seconds, so I have used videoview  method `setOnCompletionListener`(...)  in order to start the video again, however, this provide bad  experience for the viewer, because it stop every 23 seconds and start again, also miss several frames.

**So my question is " how to make videoView buffer next part of video while playing current buffered video.**

here is my code

```
    public class TvActivity extends Activity {

    // Declare variables
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    VideoView videoview;


    // Insert your Video URL
    String VideoURL = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the layout from video_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.videoview_main);
        // Find your VideoView in your video_main.xml layout
        videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        // Execute StreamVideo AsyncTask
        VideoURL = "http://ns3622101.ip-149-202-201.eu:8000/live/fr443500/75019pa/286.ts";

        // Create a progressbar
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(TvActivity.this);
        // Set progressbar title
        pDialog.setTitle("Video Streaming ");
        // Set progressbar message
        pDialog.setMessage("buffering ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        // Show progressbar
        pDialog.show();

        try {
            // Start the MediaController
            final MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                    TvActivity.this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);

            // Get the URL from String VideoURL
            final Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
            videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            videoview.setVideoURI(video);
            videoview.requestFocus();
            videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                // Close the progress bar and play the video
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    videoview.start();
                }
            });

            videoview.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    videoview.stopPlayback();
                    videoview.setVideoURI(video);
                    videoview.requestFocus();
                    videoview.start();
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }



}
```

Answer (score 5):

As you are playing video from Live Stream URL I suggest you to Stream video by using third party Player to stream video and for buffer the next part of video, I suggest you to use Android **GirrafePlayer** it's good Player get it from [here](https://github.com/tcking/GiraffePlayer)

And `as you are Streaming` **.ts** `file` I don't think android videoview will stream this video file so try to stream this video file with **.ts** file streaming supported Player.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I have tested GirrafePlayer , it is really nice player, but even in GirrafePlayer  the issues still persist. I  think the problem in the VideoView, we need some way to buffer next video part while current part is playing.

Comment: Actually you are playing **.ts** file and as I know **.ts** file will not stream directly. It play with playlist **M3U8** file... do R&D on this I dnt know more on that.

Answer (score 1):

For Live streaming and also for off-line audio or video playing I suggest used [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)

Which is very good library for playing audio and video developed by Google.
Short Intro is given bellow:

"ExoPlayer is an application level media player for Android. It provides an alternative to Android’s MediaPlayer API for playing audio and video both locally and over the Internet. ExoPlayer supports features not currently supported by Android’s MediaPlayer API, including DASH and SmoothStreaming adaptive playbacks. Unlike the MediaPlayer API, ExoPlayer is easy to customize and extend, and can be updated through Play Store application updates."

for more info search ExoPlayer on [Github](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer).

Comment: thanks for the answer, I will check it and provide the results.